# How to save an object in an xml file using Android?

Tags: android

I tried to use Xml encoder but it seems that it is not working in Android.So is there anyone to help me to find a solution ?

Comment: Serialize the object to a json using Gson and the you can save that string into xml.

Comment: i can't use json .it's only about xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jdom library [jdom](http://www.jdom.org/index.html)

to create and read xml file.